# How to go about isolating dollar amounts using Regex?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, pdf, pdfplumber

I used the PDFPlumber library to extract all the lines in my PDF, a sample line extract looks like this:

> Total Return Transportation   $16.01

The goal is to put all of these into a data frame. How do I use regex to group this line so that I may isolate the charge type and dollar amount?

Currently, I have:

```
totals=re.compile(r"(\ATotal) ([\w]+) ([\w]*)")
for line in text.split("\n"):
    line2=totals.search(line)
    if line2:
        print(line)
        print(line2.group(1))
    else:
        pass
```

Group 1 returns "Total", Group 2 returns "Return" and Group 3 "Transportation" but I'm unable to make a group that retrieves the dollar amount. Any suggestions?

Note: Dollar amounts over $1000 contain a "," that might need to be included in the regex syntax

Answer (score 0):

Just change your regex like so:

```
totals=re.compile(r"(\ATotal) ([\w]+) ([\w]*) ([\$ ]+?(\d+([,\.\d]+)?))")
>>> totals.search("Total Return Transportation $16.01").group(4)
'$16.01'
>>> totals.search("Total Return Transportation $1,006.01").group(4)
'$1,006.01'
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please could you accept the answer so the question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pattern with 4 capture groups.

Note that you can write `[\w]` as just `\w`.

Using `\w*` matches optional word characters, and could possibly also match an empty string.

You can match the word characters 1+ times, and use a pattern for the dollar amount matching 1-3 digits at the left and optional parts of a comma and 3 digits in between.

```
\A(Total) (\w+) (\w+) (\$\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\S)
```

- `\A` Start of string
- `(Total)`  Capture Total in group 1 and match a space
- `(\w+)`  Capture 1+ word chars in group 2 and match a space
- `(\w+)`  Capture 1+ word chars in group 3 and match a space
- `(` Capture **group 4**

  - `\$\d{1,3}` Match `$` and 1-3 digits
  - `(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?` Optionally repeat 3 digits and optionally match `.` and 1+ digits
- `)` Close group 4
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right to prevent a partial match

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zqvnoh/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/u7psw8).

```
import re
 
strings = [
    "Total Return Transportation $16.01",
    "Total Return Transportation $123,899,116.01",
    "Total Return Transportation $1612.01"
]
 
pattern = r"\A(Total) (\w+) (\w+) (\$\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\S)"
 
for s in strings:
    match = re.match(pattern, s)
    if match:
        print(match.group(4))
```

Output

```
$16.01
$123,899,116.01
```